Keras Library not working in google colab
Working on image recognition based ML model.
The following code line is showing error.
"from keras.utils import np_utils, to_categorical"
working on google colab
Error displayed-
"cannot import name 'np_utils' from 'keras.utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/init.py)

NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt."
Although I have already used the following-
!pip install keras
Have the latest version imported
Import packages and set numpy random seed
import random
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import np_utils, to_categorical
from keras_preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from os import listdir
from os.path import isdir, join
Load pre-shuffled training and test datasets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = sign_language.load_data()
These are first few lines of code and error on line the 3rd line.

I am currently using tensorflowversion 2.17 that the np_utils module is no longer available in keras.utils ,we can use the following command from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical . Please refer to the gist to see the following changes
